# How to check sql execute query data is null in logic app expression?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In logic app after executing `SQL_Exceute_Query` I got result like below -

```
{
  "OutputParameters": {},
  "ResultSets": {}
}
```

How can I check `ResultSets` do not have any data using expression?

I tried like `body('Exceute_a_sql_query')?['ResultSets'] is not equal to '{}'` in `condition connector`  but not working for me.

If `body('Exceute_a_sql_query')?['ResultSets'] having data go to if otherwise go to else`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried both `is equal to` and `is not equal to`, they both work. However you couldn't define it with designer flow, you have to define it with `Code view`, or it won't accept `{}` as a value.

[image]

I define a variable with the `ResultSets` value.

[image]

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution if you don't want to init a variable is to write it as:

```
  "expression": {
    "and": [
      {
        "not": {
          "equals": [
            "@{body('Exceute_a_sql_query')?['ResultSets']}",
            "{}"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

But as said before, you need to edit the expression in `Code view`. And make sure that {} are around the body statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
                "expression": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "equals": [
                            "@empty(body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets'])",
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
```